# Fuel consumption and transportable mass correlation

Tags: classical-mechanics

A question popped up into my head few month ago: «If I give a ride for one more person — how much fuel consumption changes?». If I'm going somewhere and take one more person it's usually assumed that there is cost for me. But car spends more fuel.

Obviously there should be similar question covered on the internet but I was not able to find it. Probably because of the loose formulation.

I'm bad at physics (although applied math student) and believe it must be linear connection somehow derived from [brake-specific fuel consumption equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake-specific_fuel_consumption).

I [asked this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/cy9bzd/fuel_consumption_and_transportable_mass/) on reddit/r/AskPhysics few days ago and didn't get much help. Hope it's not because it's stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're driving at perfectly constant speed your fuel consumption will barely be affected by the number of passengers.

But no car can maintain constant speed for very long, as braking, stopping and re-accelerating are inevitable on an actual public road.

An acceleration $a$, in accordance with Newton's Laws, requires a force $F$ to be exerted on the car, so that:

$$\boxed{F=ma}$$

where $m$ is the total weight of the car; driver and passengers included.

So to achieve the required acceleration, the engine has to develop more torque and more power, which increases fuel consumption (*).

It also explain why HGVs have much more powerful engines and use more fuel, than ordinary cars.

---

(*) This can be shown mathematically as follows.

Assume uniform acceleration from $0$ to velocity $v$.

$$v(t)=at$$
$$v=a\Delta t$$
$$v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$$

Work $W$ done by $F$ on the car during acceleration:

$$\text{d}W=F\text{d}x\to W=F\Delta x$$

$$W=Fv\Delta t$$
Dividing by $\Delta t$ gives power $P$:

$$\boxed{P=\frac{W}{\Delta t}=Fv=mav}$$

Comment: For reference, [HGV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_goods_vehicle) is EU parlance for what Americans would call [a *semi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-trailer_truck).

Answer (score 0):

The fuel consumption depends on the kinetic energy you need. If want to drive with the same "average speed" with more person, your kinetic energy will increase.  Before, you needed to speed up you and you car. Now, the persons mass is also included. So you need more kinetic energy. You can take the ratios of the needed kinetic energy of the two cases and equate them to the rate of fuel the consume. (Asuming that the car engine has the same efficiency along the path so that the consumed fuel and achieved kinetic energy are proportional to each other.)